# Pygame animation using mutiple images overlapping/not working

Tags: python, animation, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("TEST2")

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)

moveX,moveY=0,0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Sprite:

    def __init__(self,x,y):

        self.x=x

        self.y=y

        self.width=100

        self.height=110

        self.i100 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite0.PNG")

        self.i1 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite1.PNG")

        self.i2 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite2.PNG")

        self.i3 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite3.PNG")

        self.i4 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite4.PNG")

        self.i5 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite5.PNG")

        self.i6 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite6.PNG")

        self.i7 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite7.PNG")

        self.i8 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite8.PNG")

        self.i9 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite9.PNG")

        self.i10 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite10.PNG")

        self.i11 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite11.PNG")

        self.timeTarget=10

        self.timeNum=0

        self.currentImage=0

    def update(self):

        self.timeNum+=1

        if(self.timeNum==self.timeTarget):

            if (self.currentImage==0):

                self.currentImage+=1

            else:
                self.currentImage=0

            self.timeNum=0

        self.render()

    def render(self):

        if (self.currentImage==0):

            window.blit(self.i100, (self.x,self.y))

        else:

            window.blit(self.i1, (self.x,self.y))

            window.blit(self.i2, (self.x,self.y))

            window.blit(self.i3, (self.x,self.y))

player=Sprite(110,100)
gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:

            gameLoop = False

        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

            if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

                moveX = -3

            if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

                moveX = 3

            if (event.key==pygame.K_UP):

                moveY = -3

            if (event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):

                moveY = 3

        if (event.type==pygame.KEYUP):

            if (event.key==pygame.K_LEFT):

                moveX=0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT):

                moveX=0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_UP):

                moveY=0

            if (event.key==pygame.K_DOWN):

                moveY=0

    window.fill(black)

    player.x+=moveX

    player.x+=moveY

    player.update()

    clock.tick(50)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

What im doing is trying to animate 11 photos into an animation with pygame. this code works but when I run it the pictures seem to almost overlap. I did `window.blit` for the first few images and put them under `else`? I feel like I rendered them wrong. also I must add im really bad at picking up what people are trying to say and best learn from examples. Thanks!

Comment: Use list of images `images = []`. It is easer to use `for` to load all images, and it is easer to get next image from list to blit on screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BTW:** your code could look like this:

I use my images in example but there are still lines with your images.

I use timer to change images.
You can press space to pause and escape to exit.

etc.

```
import pygame

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Sprite:

    def __init__(self, x, y, curren_time):

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 110)

        self.images = []

        #for x in range(12):
        for x in range(1,4):
            img = pygame.image.load("ball" + str(x) +".png")
            #img = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Trevor/SkyDrive/Documents/TEST2.0/Sprite" + str(x) +".PNG")
            self.images.append( img )

        self.current_image = 0

        self.time_num = 100 # miliseconds
        self.time_target = curren_time + self.time_num

    def update(self, curren_time):

        if curren_time >= self.time_target:

            self.time_target = curren_time + self.time_num

            self.current_image += 1

            if self.current_image == len(self.images):
                self.current_image = 0


    def render(self, window):

        window.blit(self.images[self.current_image], self.rect)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONSTANS - uppercase

BLACK = (0  ,0  ,0  )
WHITE = (255,255,255)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# MAIN

def main():

    pygame.init()

    window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    pygame.display.set_caption("TEST2")

    move_x, move_y = 0, 0

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    curren_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    player = Sprite(110,100, curren_time)

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 150)
    pause_text = font.render("PAUSE", 1, WHITE)
    pause_rect = pause_text.get_rect( center = window.get_rect().center ) # center text on screen

    # mainloop

    state_game = True
    state_pause = False

    while state_game:

        curren_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        # events

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                state_game = False

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    state_game = False

                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    state_pause = not state_pause

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    move_x = -3

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    move_x = 3

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    move_y = -3

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    move_y = 3

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

                if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    move_x = 0

                elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                    move_y = 0

        # moves

        if not state_pause:
            player.rect.x += move_x
            player.rect.y += move_y
            player.update(curren_time)

        # draws

        window.fill(BLACK)

        player.render(window)

        if state_pause:
            window.blit(pause_text, pause_rect)

        pygame.display.flip()

        # FPS

        clock.tick(50)

    # the end

    pygame.quit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

[image: ball1.png] ball1.png
[image: ball2.png] ball2.png
[image: ball3.png] ball3.png

Answer (score 2):

By putting all those `window.blit(...)` calls one after another, you *are* drawing those three frames on top of each other.  Even if your computer lagged for a second between each call, you still wouldn't see them individually because they all can't appear until `pygame.display.flip()` is called.

You should store the images in a list, and keep a counter like `currentFrame` that loops from `0` to `number_of_frames-1` (or `len(frames)-1`).  Then each frame of the game you do something like this:

```
class Player:
...
def draw(window):
    window.blit(self.frames[self.currentFrame])
```